# Check for `None` or invalid data in dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

With frozen dataclasses we have something which resembles immutability. But when creating one such instance, I want to be sure that the init data is actually valid. Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import datetime 

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Employee:
    employeeId: str # should never be None
    name: str # should never be None or empty
    dateOfBirth: datetime.date # could be None if unknown
```

Is there a way to specify these conditions (probably through annotations) so that we get a `ValueError` if the condition is not met?

Comment: The last field could be specified as `dateOfBirth: Optional[datetime.date]` to indicate that `None` is an acceptable value. Still no checking though.

Comment: @Arne Yes! Given that `None` is a separate type, this works for none-checking. For other value checks (e.g string not empty) we can use __post_init__()